# AJAX Call Without jQuery For Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a bookmarklet that saves a webpage's url (and the current_user's id from my application), but it only works on pages that have jQuery available. I need to make an AJAX call without jQuery and am having a lot of trouble. Here's the code (please note, the first part is necessary for the bookmarklet to work):

```
 javascript:var url = document.URL; var user_id = <%= current_user.id  %>;   
  $.ajax({     
    url: 'http://getinstagrab.herokuapp.com/api_test',     
    dataType: 'json',     
    method: 'get',     
    data: { content: {user_id: user_id, url: url} },     
    success: function(){       
      console.log('snatched')     
    }   
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: http://yuilibrary.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are several non jQuery AJAX libraries out there, like Yahoo's.
Take a look at the example at http://yuilibrary.com/yui/quick-start/

`YUI().use('node-load', function (Y) {
    // Replace the contents of the #content node with content.html.
    Y.one('#content').load('content.html');
});`